# "Unknown column 'geir' in 'field list'"

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote this query:

```
$query = "UPDATE encodage_answer 
             SET Answer = geir 
           WHERE encodage_question_ID = 128 
             AND encodage_ID = 305 
             AND Extra = NULL";
$insert = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

But if I run this code I always get the same error:

> Unknown column 'geir' in 'field list'

It's probably me but I think I am not saying `geir` is a column/field; what's the issue?

When I run this query directly in my PHPMyAdmin it works great.

**Update: Full code:**

The answer exists, $Extra variable is Null

```
$AnswerExists = answer_exists($Question_ID, $encodage_ID, $Extra);
            if($AnswerExists <> ""){
                if($Answer != NULL){
                    $correctAnswer = mysql_prep($Answer);
                    if($Extra != NULL){
                        $query = "UPDATE `encodage_answer` SET `Answer` = '" . mysql_prep($Answer) . "' WHERE `ID` = '" . $AnswerExists . "'";
                        $insert = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
                        $query2 = "UPDATE `encodage_answer` SET `Extra` = '" . $Extra . "' WHERE `ID` = '" . $AnswerExists . "'";
                        $insert = mysql_query($query2, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
                    }else{
                        $querytest = "UPDATE `encodage_answer` SET Answer = " . $Answer . " WHERE ID = " . $AnswerExists;
                        $insert = mysql_query($querytest, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
                    }
                }
            }

function answer_exists($Question_ID, $encodage_ID, $Extra){
        global $connection;
        $trfa = false;
        echo $Question_ID . " - " . $encodage_ID . "<br />";
        if($Extra <> ""){
            $query = "SELECT * 
                FROM encodage_answer
                WHERE encodage_ID = {$encodage_ID} AND encodage_question_ID = {$Question_ID} AND Extra = {$Extra}";
        }else{
            $query = "SELECT * 
                FROM encodage_answer
                WHERE encodage_ID = {$encodage_ID} AND encodage_question_ID = {$Question_ID}";
        }
```

Comment: If 'geir' isn't a column, what is it? Is it a raw string? This shouldn't work in PHPMyAdmin, either. Maybe it's just not showing you the error?

Comment: @zanlok: geir indeed is a raw string. It's a value entered by a user in a text-field.

Answer (score 6):

Try putting single quotes around `geir`. By not quoting the string you want to set the column to, the SQL backend thinks you want to set the value of the `Answer` column to the value of the `geir` column. Since the `geir` column doesn't exist in your table, it throws an error.

**Edit:** I suspect that PHPMyAdmin has some kind of SQL statement filtering to catch cases like this, and automatically puts quotes around the string for you.

Comment: Hi CanSpiceI keep having the same problem. I created a simpler query but the result is the same: UPDATE `encodage_answer` SET `Answer` = 'geir' WHERE `ID` = '25018'Unknown column 'geir' in 'where clause'

Comment: @Jens: do you have another query on this page?

Comment: @Mark: yes I have a lot of other queries on the page but no other update queries.

Comment: @Jens: any others that have `geir` in them? There's no error in your updated query, and no mention of `geir` in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @Mark: The "geir" is just a value entered by a user in a textfield as value. I'm sure it's never used in a Where clause

Comment: @Jens: I doubt your database is lying to you when it says "Unknown column 'geir' in 'where clause'"

Comment: @Mark: I was thinking the same thing :-) This is how I build the query: $querytest = "UPDATE `encodage_answer` SET Answer = " . $Answer . " WHERE ID = " . $AnswerExists; And the answer of the variable $Answer  appears to be 'geir'

Comment: @Jens: Look into placeholders and bind values. The way you're building your queries means you will get hacked. See also http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help to everyone! I'm changing all queries to a safer format! SQL-Injection treats are no longer an issue! Thanks for the tip!

Concerning my question:
I'am a complete idiot! After searching for a solution for 20 hours I found my error! The error was for another query. I'm very sorry for wasting your time but I'm a newbie (ergo, the sql-injection issue), so I hope I am allowed to make a few mistakes.

Thanks

Jens